# How would I run DELETE queries on a Master Without Executing Same DELETEs on a Slave?

Tags: mysql, replication

If I want to run a query that will only execute on the master mysql server and not the slave. assuming we have an environment with replication through query logs. Could I and how?

The idea is to have some records that are archived on the slave. Lets say the master is a production website and only requires data that has been entered in the past month to operate correctly but the slave is where data from years will be saved and later analyzed to change variable on the main (production/master) server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## ***There is a much, much simpler way***

A Replication Slave relies on the Master's binary logs so as to ship SQL from them into the Slave's local relay logs. Just *tell the Master not to record the SQL*

```
SQLSTMT="SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} DELETE FROM tablename WHERE column='our filters'"
mysql -u... -p... -Ae"${SQLSTMT}"
```

The key here is to disable binary logging in its session. The Slave won't know what hit the Master because the Master will execute the `DELETE` and **not record the `DELETE`**.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: +1 sorry for the couple years of delay in selecting this as an answer, I didn't see this until now :).

Answer (score 1):

The only way is for you to have another table with the same data and **exclude** that from replication in `my.cnf`.

MySQL's replication is going to copy and execute every statement you perform on the relevant tables and/or databases. So when you execute something on the master, the slave will also execute it given that it was targeted at a table on the do-replicate list.

Now, your solution would be to create table `B` and copy over all contents of table `A`. Add an additional field to table `B` called `custom` for example. Run a cronjob every X minutes/hours/days/months to:

1. Delete all rows in table `B` where `custom = 0`
2. Insert all rows from table `A` into table `B`: `INSERT INTO b (SELECT * FROM a);`
3. You can optionally use a date range for deleting and inserting new rows which will considerably reduce the amount of work needing to be done for this operation.
4. Run your queries on the master server and to table `B`, with `custom = 1`.

Hope this helps.