# Data Warehousing strategy

Tags: mysql

I have a busy MySQL database with 1.6 million records a day, I'm looking to replicate this data to another server, then run a clean up job on production database to maintain small database in production.

I thought about Master / Slave setup, but I'm not sure how can I prevent deletes from replicating to slave.

I'm sure other BD admins / developers have run into same situation, I would appreciate any suggestion / recommendation

Thank you

Comment: Why is this a Data Warehouse strategy? Are you planning to do some aggregation on this data or any ETL transformation? Or is it more of a "Remove old data from main production db and leave there only useful (last year..you define useful) data and have historical data on a secondary server"?

Comment: I do have number of databases and planning on using a data  warehouseing engine "infinidb" to gather all data on a dedicated server for reporting.  

I'm not planning to do any ETL transformation, Just wanted to know what is the best way to get done.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought about Master / Slave setup, but I'm not sure how can I prevent deletes from replicating to slave.

You can't do that. Replication is intended to replicate as much as possible to keep the slaves as accurate copies of the master(s).

You might want to replicate to another machine so that you can have a copy to run the copy-to-archive archive process on, so that this does not impact performance of the application when being run, but that is optional (and not necessary if the process doesn't impact live performance much or you have a time window in which you don't care if it does (i.e. over-night if your application is predominantly used in one timezone so you have quiet periods when most users are sleeping)).

The most efficient way to update the archive/reporting database from the production one (either the main DB or a read-only replica), and clean up production once this is done, depends a lot on the structure of your data.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20020/how-would-i-run-delete-queries-on-a-master-without-executing-same-deletes-on-a-s

Comment: @ninjabber: So it is *possible*, though that technique feels rather "dirty" to me. Deliberately circumventing a process intended for maintaining consistency. All the business logic (stored procedures and triggers in the DB and everything in apps outside that modify data in it) will need to make sure that "don't log this" option is set at the right times and only at the right times - that seems to be an open invitation for some interesting bugs!

Comment: I agree with what you say, just wanted to mention the dirty alternative